# Call Python functions from TCL script with arguments

Tags: python, tcl

I have a Python script, say, `sample.py` with 2 functions `func1()` and `func2()`:

```
def func1():
    print("Called Function 1")

def func2():
    print("Called Function 2")
```

How do I call this function `func2()` from the Tcl script and also how to pass the arguments to that function?

Comment: Do you want them to be in the same process?

Comment: yes Donal Fellows.... its better if its in same process..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python code needs this (I called it junk.py and put it in the same folder with tcl script).

```
import sys

def func1():
    print("Called Function 1")

def func2():
    print("Called Function 2")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    eval(sys.argv[1] + '()')
```

Tcl file called test_tcl.tcl:

```
set out [exec python junk.py [lindex $argv 0]]
puts $out
```

Execute from command line:

```
tclsh test_tcl.tcl func1
```

Output is:

```
Called Function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The best method is probably to see if [tclpython](http://jfontain.free.fr/tclpython.htm) will work for you. (Download links on http://jfontain.free.fr/; pick the one(s) you need.) That should let you write code like this:

```
# Set up a python interpreter
package require tclpython
set py [python::interp new]

# Load a file in with your definitions
$py exec {
    # This is Python code, embedded directly in Tcl
    evalfile("sample.py")
}

# Evaluate a python expression (in this case, call an argument-less function)
set result [$py eval func2()]

# Dispose of the python interpreter
python::interp delete $py
```